# XQuery to change attribute value and return previous one

Tags: xquery, basex

I'm trying to update an attribute value of a node and return its previous value all in one query and I can't find a way to do it. I'm using [BaseX](http://basex.org/) as my XML/XQuery database.

For now I've tried doing this:

```
/Root/Elem/properties/property[@id='17']/@format,
replace value of node /Root/Elem/properties/property[@id='17']/@format with 'URL'
```

and also this:

```
for $prop in /Root/Elem/properties/property[@id='17']
    let $format := $prop/@format
    return (replace value of node $prop/@format with 'URL', $format)
```

And multiple other tests but they all lead to the following error:

```
List expression: no updating expression allowed.
```

Is it a limitation of BaseX or is it not possible in XQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*XQuery Update* does not allow returning results from an updating query. You can however use BaseX's proprietary [`update:output($seq)`](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Update_Module#update:output) function to do that:

```
for $prop in /Root/Elem/properties/property[@id='17']
let $format := $prop/@format
return (replace value of node $format with 'URL', update:output($format))
```

Comment: Yes I've seen the proprietary function in BaseX documentation but was hoping for a more generic method. So in Xquery you would have to perform two successive queries to get a value and then change it? There is no other method? what about transform methods?

Comment: There is no other method in BaseX/XQuery Update. Transformations aren't persistant, so you can only change a temporary copy. Maybe it is also possible using [XQuery Scripting Extension](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-sx-10/), but I don't know it and BaseX doesn't support it yet, either.

Comment: Regarding the official XQuery Update Facility, you may be lucky to hear that there are some plans to support both updates and results in XQUF 3.1.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. At least now I know it's a real limitation of XQuery (for now) and that BaseX provides an alternative.